# How can I insert a value from another table to another on insertion?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

I have this table called `users`. Whenever I sign up a user, I generate an UUID for him. When this UUID is generated I want to insert a row in another table called `health`, with the same UUID that was inserted on the users table.

I was trying to make this way, but I can't make it work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
    RETURNS trigger AS
'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO  health(uuid) VALUES (users.uuid);

    RETURN NEW;
END;

    ' LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
    AFTER INSERT
    ON users
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test(users.uuid);
```

I'm having trouble, because there's no data that can be compared on the health table, as the row doesn't exist. The little change on syntax (the `'`) is because of the Spring JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression you'd need to pass the UUID in the function call. But that is not so. The special record `NEW` contains the new row. Use it in the function body:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
'
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO health(uuid) VALUES (NEW.uuid);  -- this!

   RETURN NULL;  -- irreleant for AFTER trigger
END
';

CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION test();  -- no parameter!
```

Basics in the manual:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/triggers.html

For Postgres 10 or older use the (misleading) [keyword `PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) instead (no difference, new syntax is just more reasonable):

```
...
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test();  -- no parameter!
```